# C Map String to Function

Tags: c, string, shell, dictionary, function-pointers

So, I'm making a Unix minishell, and have come to a roadblock. I need to be able to execute built-in functions, so I made a function:

```
int exec_if_built_in(char **args)
```

It takes an array of strings(the first being the command, and the rest being arguments). For non built-in commands I simply use something like execvp, however I need to find a way to map the first string to a function. I was thinking of making two arrays, one of strings, and another with their corresponding function pointers. However, since many of these functions will be different(return and accept different things), this approach won't work. I also thought of making an array of structs with a name property and a function pointer property, however once again due to the varied nature of the functions I'll be using, this won't work.

So, what's the best way to execute a function based on the input of a string? How do I map a string to a certain function? I'm not very familiar with function pointers so I may be missing something.

Thank you guys for the help :)

Comment: Any sort of boundary on that ptr-ptr ? I.e. is there an argc that goes with that ? I think you may need one sooner or later, esp if commands take params and you want to validate them.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you're asking. There's a limit of 1024 characters that can be passed into the shell. I break up the string the user enters into an array of strings. I can build the functions fine, I just need to find a way to call a function associated with its string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was thinking of making two arrays, one of strings, and another with their corresponding function pointers.

That is the right approach. Make wrapper functions that take arguments of identical type<sup>*</sup> then call the "real" functions from inside your wrappers.

If you would like to "earn additional points for style", sort the array of strings alphabetically, and use binary search on the array of strings. This will let you save a few CPU cycles when the two arrays get bigger.

---

<sup>*</sup> Perhaps you could use `char **`, because that's what your `exec_if_built_in` takes.

Comment: Ohh, but what about its return value? Good job on figuring out a way to pass anything.


I don't quite understand what an identical type* is, or what a real function is.

Comment: @Scriptonaut The asterisk there is to direct you to the footnote about `char**`. As far as the return type goes, make sure they all return the same thing, too. `int` sounds like a good candidate. Essentially, your `exec_if_built_in` will be the first level of dispatch: it will pick a command by name, and pass control to the wrapper implementing it. The wrapper can then use real functions as much as it needs, and return an `int` that `exec_if_built_in` will return to its callers. Each command will have its own wrapper capable of executing the command.

Comment: Could you explain to me exactly what a wrapper is? Do you just mean creating a new function for each prototype, and then within calling a specific function that will actually do the work?


Sorry for the confusion, while I've programmed quite a bit of stuff, C is not at all familiar.

Comment: @Scriptonaut Yes, you got the meaning of "wrapper" exactly right: that's a function with the signature expected by the top-level searcher that calls a specific function that will actually do the work, perhaps after pulling its arguments from the `char**` array of arguments, or doing something similar.

Answer (score 1):

If your cases are so varied that a table-driven approach is inappropriate, then maybe an if/else-if cascade is the best solution.

```
if(!strcmp(args[0], "cat")) {
    /* cat a file */
} else if(!strcmp(args[0], "dog")) {
    /* dog a file */
} else if(!strcmp(args[0], "echo")) {
    /* create an echo chamber */
} ...
```

Comment: The problem isn't finding a match with a string, it's how I would execute the function once I find a match. Am I missing something?

Comment: Here you'd just put the function invocation e.g. where it says `/* cat a file */`...

Comment: This is something I could totally achieve, however my assignment(I'm a CS major) said to avoid if/else-if cascades. I'll still do this if I can't figure something a bit more elegant out(I won't be deducted very much).


Seriously, thank you for the help. I've been banging my head against the wall for the last 11 hours.

Comment: Ah. In that case, I would use a table, something like `struct builtin { const char *name; int (*func)(const char **args); } builtin_funcs[] = { {"cat", cat_func}, {"dog", dog_func}, {NULL, NULL} };` where `cat_func` is declared `int cat_func(const char **args);`. You can search the list with `struct builtin *cur = builtin_funcs; while(cur->name) { if(!strcmp(cur->name, args[0])) cur->func(args); }`.

Comment: The above is essentially a code version of @dasblinkenlight's answer; the functions accept `char **` and return `int` (like real console functions do).

Comment: This is what I'm going to do, thanks. One question, rather than aggregately assigning the structs with cat_func, shouldn't I do &cat_func? This is the first time I've ever used function pointers so I'm not quite sure on it.